# Translating a PostgreSQL operator to a MySQL equivalent?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Hi I have the following PostgreSQL statement:

```
SELECT sub1.date_evt AS event_date, SUM(sub1.UC_IP) as UCIP, SUM(sub1.NON_UC_IP) as OUTIP
        FROM (
            SELECT  TO_CHAR(event_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as date_evt,
            case when ip <<= inet('10.0.0.0/8') then 1
            when ip <<= inet('128.218.0.0/16') then 1
            else 0 END AS UC_IP,
            case when  ip <= inet('10.0.0.0/8') then 0
            when ip <<= inet('128.218.0.0/16') then 0
            else 1
            END AS NON_UC_IP
            FROM link_history
            WHERE url_link = (SELECT `id` FROM links WHERE base_url = 'qt4gt8')
        ) AS sub1
        GROUP BY sub1.date_evt
        ORDER BY sub1.date_evt;
```

I am trying to translate it into something identical in MySQL, I have converted the data already and imported it into MySQL, the IP values have been saved using the  INET_NTOA() function into an unsigned INT column in the MySQL database.

I have attempted to convert this but cannot find the answer to the operator **<<=** this operator I don't know what it does and cannot find documentation on the PostgreSQL website.

I thought maybe it was a bitwise equals operator or something, but I can't seem to make it work in MySQL, here is my MySQL statement.

```
SELECT sub1.date_evt AS event_date, SUM(sub1.UC_IP) as UCIP, SUM(sub1.NON_UC_IP) as OUTIP
        FROM (
            SELECT event_date as date_evt,
            case 
                when ip << INET_ATON('10.0.0.8') then 1
                when ip << INET_ATON('128.218.0.16') then 1
            else 0 END AS UC_IP,
            case 
                when ip << INET_ATON('10.0.0.8') then 0
                when ip << INET_ATON('128.218.0.16') then 0
            else 1
            END AS NON_UC_IP FROM link_history
            WHERE url_link = (SELECT `id` FROM links WHERE base_url = 'qt4gt8')
        ) AS sub1
        GROUP BY sub1.date_evt
        ORDER BY sub1.date_evt;
```

When running this I get no results, which is incorrect, I should get 16 rows from my dataset.

Also MySQL doesn't seem to like the IP range value such as '169.230.0.0/16' so I have just placed it in the highest range for the given IP by deleting the 0\ and keeping it either 8/16 for the given IP, I am not sure if this will work the same.  But without knowing how to resolve for **<<=** I cannot fix the rest of the query.

UPDATE:
Ok with the latest information I was given I have the following query:

```
SELECT sub1.date_evt AS event_date, SUM(sub1.UC_IP) as UCIP, SUM(sub1.NON_UC_IP) as OUTIP
        FROM (
            SELECT event_date as date_evt,
            case 
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') + (1 << (32-8) - 1)) THEN 1 #8
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) then 1  #128.218.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) then 1 #64.54.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) then 1  #169.230.0.16
            else 0 END AS UC_IP,
            case 
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') + (1 << (32-8) - 1)) THEN 0 #8
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) THEN 0  #128.218.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) -1)) THEN 0 #64.54.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) THEN 0  #169.230.0.16
            else 1
            END AS NON_UC_IP FROM link_history
            WHERE url_link = (SELECT `id` FROM links WHERE base_url = 'qt4gt8')
        ) AS sub1
        GROUP BY sub1.date_evt
        ORDER BY sub1.date_evt
```

AND my database table now looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `link_history` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url_link` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidr` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_url` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=930100 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



id  url_link event_date         ip              cidr     ref_url
3204    70  2011-02-05 07:20:00 67.180.61.248   32       http://ucsfmeded.blogspot.com/2010/11/calvin-chou-md-phd-appointed-academy.html
```

However I am finding that the results from the MYSQL table do not exactly match the results from the Postgres table.   In PostgreSQL I get 16 results for the data, in the MySQL I am getting 29 rows.   The SUM columns are also off.  It looks to me like the GROUP BY is not working because of the time allocation.  Do I have to break the DATE-TIME up into separate columns or is there a way to do a GROUP BY where it is only counting the DATE?  How can I be sure the IP RANGE is working properly?

Comment: Yep, resolved below, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-net.html) is known 'Is contained within or or equals'

```
when ip <<= inet('128.218.0.0/16') then 1
```

so what you are doing here is trying to find out if your ip belongs to the 128.218.0.0/16 network. That is whether the IP address is within 128.218.0.0 to 128.218.0.255

So you can do this with a numeric comparision. But the question is why are you moving from a feature rich, more powerfull, faster database to a one that does not have so many features, slower and in some cases down right broken?

The above is roughly equivalent to

```
when ip >= inet_aton('128.218.0.0') AND ip <= INET_ATON('128.218.0.255) then 1
```

Similarly

```
when ip >= inet_aton('10.0.0.0') AND ip <= INET_ATON('10.0.255.255) then 1
```

Comment: hahaha, funny answer, unfortunately that was just the task I was given, I think I can use the BETWEEN ... AND ... functions to do something similar, thanks.

Comment: yes you would have to convert each of those networks to a lower and upper address

Comment: Trying to use the following between but it doesn't appear to return anything, the IP is already stored as a unsigned INT,   `WHEN ip BETWEEN INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') AND INET_ATON('10.0.0.8') then 1`

Comment: because 10.0.0.0/8 doesn't meean 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.8 here 8 is a subnet mask. I recommend reading up a bit on it before continuing. Then when itn doubt you can use an IP address calculator

Comment: @DevelumPHP `/8` means first 8 bits must be equal. So your expression should be `WHEN ip BETWEEN INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') AND INET_ATON('10.255.255.255')`

Answer (score 1):

```
ip <<= inet('10.0.0.0/8')
```

would be

```
ip >> (32-8) = INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') >> (32-8)
```

Consider that this way you can not use an index. But it doesn' matter for your query.

If you want to search for IPs in a range using an index, you can use a BETWEEN condition:

```
ip BETWEEN INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') AND INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') + (1 << (32-8)) - 1
```

If you store your ips as string and your subnet mask is `/8`, `/16` or `/24` then you can just compare with `LIKE`.

`/8` means - first number is equal.
`/16` means - first two numbers are equal.
`/24` means - first three numbers are equal.

So to chek if the ip is in the `10.0.0.0/8` range, you can simply use

```
ip LIKE '10.%'
```

For the `'128.218.0.0/16'` range:

```
ip LIKE '128.218.%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks everyone (@e4c5 and @Paul Spiegel) for the helpful answers. Here is the final working query.

```
SELECT sub1.date_evt AS event_date, SUM(sub1.UC_IP) as UCIP, SUM(sub1.NON_UC_IP) as OUTIP
        FROM (
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_evt,
            case 
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') + (1 << (32-8) - 1)) THEN 1 #8
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) then 1  #128.218.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) then 1 #64.54.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) then 1  #169.230.0.16
            else 0 END AS UC_IP,
            case 
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('10.0.0.0') + (1 << (32-8) - 1)) THEN 0 #8
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('128.218.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) THEN 0  #128.218.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('64.54.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) -1)) THEN 0 #64.54.0.16
                WHEN INET_ATON(ip) >= INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') AND INET_ATON(ip) <= (INET_ATON('169.230.0.0') + (1 << (32-16) - 1)) THEN 0  #169.230.0.16
            else 1
            END AS NON_UC_IP FROM link_history
            WHERE url_link = (SELECT `id` FROM links WHERE base_url = 'qt4gt8')
        ) AS sub1
        GROUP BY sub1.date_evt
        ORDER BY sub1.date_evt
```